# Best way to delete memory for objects from vector

Tags: c++, vector, heap-memory

I have vector which contains the objects allocated on heap. I want to delete some of the element from the vector. Which is the best way to remove element from vector and delete it.

The one way is tried in the below code:

```
class MyObj
{
    bool rem;
public:
    MyObj(bool r) : rem(r) { cout << "MyObj" << endl; }
    ~MyObj() { cout << "~MyObj" << endl; }

    bool shouldRemove() const noexcept { return rem; }
};


int main()
{
    vector<MyObj*> objs;
    objs.push_back(new MyObj(false));
    objs.push_back(new MyObj(true));
    objs.push_back(new MyObj(false));
    objs.push_back(new MyObj(true));

    auto itr =  objs.begin();
    while (itr != objs.end())
    {
        if ((*itr)->shouldRemove())
        {
            delete *itr;
            *itr = nullptr;

            itr = objs.erase(itr);
        }
        else
            ++itr;
    }

    // size will be two
    cout << "objs.size() :" << objs.size() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not store the object directly, i.e. use `vector<MyObj>`?

Comment: Don't use raw pointers. Choose between `vector<MyObj>`, `vector<unique_ptr<MyObj>>` and `vector<shared_ptr<MyObj>>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your loop is fine, as far as removing and `delete`'ing objects (the `nullptr` assignment is unnecessary). But the rest of your code is prone to memory leaks. If `push_back()` throws, you leak the object you just `new`'ed.  And you are not `delete`'ing the objects that are still in the vector after your loop ends.

> Which is the best way to remove element from vector and delete it

The *best* option is to not use raw pointers at all. Store actual object instances directly in the vector, and let the vector destruct the instances for you when you remove them, and when the vector itself is destructed when it goes out of scope:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<MyObj> objs;

    objs.emplace_back(false);
    objs.emplace_back(true);
    objs.emplace_back(false);
    objs.emplace_back(true);

    auto itr = objs.begin();
    while (itr != objs.end()) {
        if (itr->shouldRemove())
            itr = objs.erase(itr);
        else
            ++itr;
    }

    /* alternatively:
    objs.erase(
        std::remove_if(objs.begin(), objs.end(),
            [](auto &o){ return o.shouldRemove(); }),   
        objs.end()
    );
    */

    // size will be two
    std::cout << "objs.size() :" << objs.size() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise, if you need to store pointers to dynamically allocated objects, at least use smart pointers to manage them:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyObj>> objs;

    objs.push_back(std::unique_ptr<MyObj>(new MyObj(false)));
    objs.push_back(std::unique_ptr<MyObj>(new MyObj(true)));
    objs.push_back(std::unique_ptr<MyObj>(new MyObj(false)));
    objs.push_back(std::unique_ptr<MyObj>(new MyObj(true)));

    /* alternatively, if you are using C++14 or later
    objs.push_back(std::make_unique<MyObj>(false));
    objs.push_back(std::make_unique_ptr<MyObj>(true));
    objs.push_back(std::make_unique<MyObj>(false));
    objs.push_back(std::make_unique<MyObj>(true));
    */

    auto itr = objs.begin();
    while (itr != objs.end()) {
        if ((*itr)->shouldRemove())
            itr = objs.erase(itr);
        else
            ++itr;
    }

    /* alternatively:
    objs.erase(
        std::remove_if(objs.begin(), objs.end(),
            [](auto &o){ return o->shouldRemove(); }),  
        objs.end()
    );
    */

    // size will be two
    std::cout << "objs.size() :" << objs.size() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `If push_back() throws` Is there a real possibility pushing back a pointer can throw?

Comment: @KillzoneKid yes, *any* insertion operation can potentially throw, if the vector is at capacity and needs to resize its internal array but fails to allocate a new array. So you should ensure that the `new`'ed pointer is properly owned before passing it to the vector, so that if the vector fails, the pointer can be `delete`'ed properly and not leak

Answer (score 2):

the best way is to use unique_ptr or (if necessary) shared_ptr.
In this case, you can use standard c++ idioms like [remove-erase idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom). An addition benefit - no memory leak.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class MyObj
{
    bool rem;
public:
    MyObj(bool r) : rem(r) { cout << "MyObj" << endl; }
    ~MyObj() { cout << "~MyObj" << endl; }

    bool shouldRemove() const noexcept { return rem; }
};


int main()
{
    vector<unique_ptr<MyObj>> objs;
    objs.emplace_back(make_unique<MyObj>(false));
    objs.emplace_back(make_unique<MyObj>(true));
    objs.emplace_back(make_unique<MyObj>(false));
    objs.emplace_back(make_unique<MyObj>(true));

    objs.erase(remove_if(objs.begin(), objs.end(), [](unique_ptr<MyObj> const & item){ return item->shouldRemove(); }),
               objs.end());

    // size will be two
    cout << "objs.size() :" << objs.size() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: just a doubt, why do we need to need to refer to each element using a unique pointer inside remove if, doesn't simply referring it by `MyObj` type work ?

Comment: predecator's parameter is vector's item type. in our case - `unique_ptr<MyObj>`

Comment: @tkhurana96 because the `value_type` of the `vector` is `unique_ptr<MyObj>` and not `MyObj`. The vector elements are each passed to the predicate, and must be convertible to what the predicate expects. But `unique_ptr` doesn't have an implicit conversion operator, so it must be passed as-is.

Comment: @Alexander the predicate's parameter can technically be any type the vector's element type can be implicitly converted to, it doesn't necessarily have to be the vector element type exactly. Except in this case, it does.

Comment: @Alexander @Remy Lebeau thanks! Complete misread the vector type to be `MyObj`